# How to quickly find the nodes that direclty or indirectly depend on a node in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph, each node has one or more directed links to other nodes. Such as below:

[image]

For C, the expected result is A, B, D, E.

For D, the expected result is A, B, E

I am considering using a breadth-first search for the node in question recursively.  Is there any quicker approach? The dependency relation is stored in a 2-column table like this:

```
A-B
B-A
B-C
B-E
D-C
D-E
E-D
E-A
```

The background of this question is, I want to update all the files that directly or indirectly depend on a file which is modified.

Comment: Contract to strongly connected components, then topological sort and traversal from the sources, making sure you visit every node only once each predecessor has been processed.

Comment: @G.Bach could you provide some more details?